# Code works in JSFiddle and Codepen but not in browser, where am I gone wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

What's the problem with the below code running?

It runs in JSFiddle and Codepen so I don't understand why it won't work just in the browser as a web page.

I see somethings about incompatibility between jQuery and SVG however why does it work in JSFiddle and CodePen if that's the case. Don't they run code pretty much as if it were a normal webpage?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMbFu/4/%20JSFiddle)
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hbqEA)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<svg width="500" height="300">
  <circle name="black" id="blackC" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#0C090A" value="7" stroke-width="4" fill="#0C090A"/>
  <circle name="blue" id="blueC" cx="150" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#3498DB" stroke-width="4" fill="#3498DB"/>
  <circle name="green" id="greenC" cx="250" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#0C090A1" stroke-width="4" fill="#2ECC71"/>
  <circle name="grey" id="greyC" cx="350" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#95A5A6" stroke-width="4" fill="#95A5A6"/>

  <circle name="purple" id="purpleC" cx="50" cy="150" r="40" stroke="#9B59B6" stroke-width="4" fill="#9B59B6"/>
  <circle name="orange" id="orangeC" cx="150" cy="150" r="40" stroke="#E67E22" stroke-width="4" fill="#E67E22"/>
  <circle name="red" id="redC" cx="250" cy="150" r="40" stroke="#C0392B" stroke-width="4" fill="#C0392B"/>
  <circle name="yellow" id="yellowC" cx="350" cy="150" r="40" stroke="#F1C40F" stroke-width="4" fill="#F1C40F"/>
 </svg>

<form id="colorgenics" method="POST" action="testCg.php" name="cgForm">  
  <input type="text" id="selection" name="selection" />
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
  <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
<br />
<button id="arrayCheck" name="arrayCh">Check Value</button>
<script language="text/javascript">
$
var numArray = [];
$("#blackC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("7", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("7");
    }
});
$("#blueC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("1", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("1");
    }
});
$("#greenC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("2", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("2");
    }
});
$("#greyC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("0", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("0");
    }
});
$("#purpleC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("5", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("5");
    }
});
$("#orangeC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("6", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("6");
    }
});
$("#redC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("3", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("3");
    }
});
$("#yellowC").on("click", function () {
    if ($.inArray("4", numArray) == -1) {
        numArray.push("4");
    }
});
$("#arrayCheck").on("click", function () {
    alert(numArray);
    $("#selection").val(numArray);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are your running this on your local machine?

Answer (score 6):

It won't work in your browser when you open it locally because it's trying to find the path to jQuery as:

```
<script src="file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So change the include to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The path:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

is meant to be a relative path from a server, which automatically compensates for `http` vs `https`, however when run locally, the browser puts a `file:` in the beginning which will fail.

Comment: This isn't it - that was just a typo.