# code working in codepen, not in browser: javascript to zoom svg on mousewheel

Tags: javascript, svg

im missing something.. I am fairly new to javascript so it's probably straightforward!?

The codepen (http://codepen.io/robertwebb364/pen/uFcHI) shows uses a matrix transform to zoom on an svg group while keeping it at the centre of the screen...

Works fine, but the exact same code does not work when running a local file in a browser on my desktop. (using mainly Chrome but have also tried firefox and safari - same result, no zoom! - and no errors reported on the console).

[Note: This post ([Code works in JSFiddle and Codepen but not in browser, where am I gone wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959004/code-works-in-jsfiddle-and-codepen-but-not-in-browser-where-am-i-gone-wrong)) reports a similar problem -  in that case it is due to how the file path to the script library is being interpreted by the browser... not an issue in my case as there are no external libraries]

Ive also tried adding a setInterval but to no avail:

```
var timer=setInterval("zoom()", 100);
```

Below is the core code:

```
function init(evt)
   {
    if ( window.svgDocument == null )
    {
      svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;
    }
    ellgroup = svgDoc.getElementById("ellgroup");
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  } 


function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
    var evt = window.event || e;
    delta=e.wheelDelta;
    cumdelta+=delta;
    if (cumdelta<0) {
    scale=-100/cumdelta;
    } else {
        scale=100/cumdelta;
    }
    zoom(scale);
    return false;
}


function zoom(scale) {
transMatrix[0] = scale*transMatrixorig[0];
transMatrix[3] = scale*transMatrixorig[3];
transMatrix[4] = transMatrixorig[4]+(xcent-(scale*xcent)); 
transMatrix[5] = transMatrixorig[5]+(ycent-(scale*ycent));

newMatrix = "matrix(" +  transMatrix.join(' ') + ")";
ellgroup.setAttribute("transform", newMatrix);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so now its working...

Comment: Errors must have crept in.. apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Now working...

Turned out to be a very small mistype after all..
the  tag was closed improperly.. should be

```
<g id="".. *etc* > // before the graphic elements to be grouped
</g> // after the graphic elements
```

In the desktop version of the code I had:

```
<g id="".. *etc* />   // spot the extra "/" !
 </g>
```